# Call Another Method After Completing An Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

I've been stuck on a problem for a while now. I have an API that has an endpoint called 'actuals' and returns a list of Performances (custom Object) in JSON format. Because of its asynchronous nature, I subscribe to an Observable. There is another method called calculateCosts that is dependent on this data so I want to fire this method only after the observable is completed.

Trimmed rundown of my component:

```
export class ProjectDetailComponent implements OnInit
{
    performances: Performance[] = [];

    constructor(
        private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
        private performanceService: PerformanceService
      ) { }

    ngOnInit(): void 
    {
      // Fetch data
      this.fetchPerformances();
    }

    fetchPerformances()
    {
      this.performanceService.getActuals().pipe(
        finalize(() => this.calculateCosts))
        .subscribe(data => {
          data.forEach(p =>
          {
            let performance = new Performance(
              p['timesheetCodeId'],
              p['firstName'],
              p['lastName'],
              p['timesheetCodeName'],
              p['actualHours']
          );
          
          this.performances.push(performance);
        })
      });
    }
  }

  calculateCosts()
  {
    console.log(this.performances);
  }
}
```

I've been able to confirm that the Observable does indeed return valid data by logging the performances array to the console in the subscribe() itself and in the finalize(). However calculateCosts never gets fired (should log performances) and I fail to understand why.

Could anyone help me steer in the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not calling the function when the observable is finalized:

```
finalize(() => this.calculateCosts))
```

Change it to:

```
finalize(() => this.calculateCosts()))
```